# Show that $\sum x^p$ over primes must have a non-trivial zero.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, number-theory, summation, prime-numbers

The sum $\sum x^n$ is unbounded in $|x| \le 1$. Similarly if $p$ is prime then trivially $\sum x^p$ is also unbounded in $|x| < 1$ because all primes $> 2$ are odd so the lower bound would approach $-\infty$ as $x \to -1$ and the upper bound would approach $\infty$ as $x \to 1$.

I observed that if we take the summation over the set of composite numbers $c$ then we have a lower bound of about $-0.424$ at about $x = -0.539$. Heuristically this is because the sum over odd composite would negate the sum over even composites so we expect that at the suitable value of $x$ the total sum would reach a minima as seen the observations below.

[image]

Also observe that $\sum x^p$ has a zero at about $-0.63$ and $\sum x^c$ has a zero at about $-0.77$.

**Question 1**: Show that even though $\sum x^n$ does not have a non-trivial zero, both $\sum x^p$ and $\sum x^c$ must have a non-trivial zero? Trivial zero is $x = 0$.

**Question 2**: Show that $\sum x^c$ must have a lower bound? Is there a closed form expression of the lower bound?

Comment: You already have all the ingredients to answer the first half of Question 1. The sum over all natural number is bounded from below, and the sum over all prime number diverges to $-\infty$ as $x\to-1$. Now realize the sum over composites as the difference between two (plus the term $x$ if you do not regard 1 as composite). This shows that the sum over composites goes to $\infty$ as $x\to\pm1$, showing that it is bounded from below.

Comment: @SangchulLee Do you mean the first half of Question 2?

Comment: For Question 1, show numerically that $\sum (-1/2)^c < \sum (-1/2)^n$ as the graph suggests. Then the existence of nontrivial zeroes follow from the Intermediate Value Theorem.

Comment: @i707107 I think in general we can prove something like this - Given any sub-interval $I$ in $(-1,0)$, it is possible to create an infinite subset $S$ of the set of natural numbers such that $\sum x^s$ has a non-trivial zero in $I$.

Comment: @i707107 wouldn't we need to prove function continuity to take advantage of the Intermediate Value Theorem?

Comment: The power series $\sum x^p$ and $\sum x^c$ have radius of convergence $1$. The power series centered at $a$ with radius of convergence $r$, is infinitely differentiable on the interval $(a-r, a+r)$.